# InputTextarea autoscroll behavior

Tags: ajax, jsf, autoscroll

I have a inputTextarea that I refresh using PrimeFaces' AJAX poll.

When the inputTextarea is refreshed, a lot of new text will be displayed. However, it will always jump to the first line after refresh. If the user wants to scroll down and the poll/refresh happens, it will jump to the top anyway.

Is there anything I can do to prevent the jumping to the top (or better: prevent jumping at all)? If not, can I make the inputTextarea stay on the bottom at least? (Since the new lines will be appended to the bottom.)

I'm using JSF 2 (MyFaces), Tomahawk and PrimeFaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use JavaScript. Include this script below the `<h:inputTextarea>` in the portion which is been updated by `<p:poll>` or in a function when the component supports `oncomplete` (not sure as I don't have recent PF documentation).

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("clientIdOfTheTextarea");
textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight; // Scrolls to bottom.
```